# How to format the group title in Kendo UI grid after I group the grid?

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I want to group the gird according to the birthday which is `datatime` type,but after grouped,I find that the group title is json format?How to format it?My codes are here:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<BLL.ViewModelStudnet> ()
              .Name("ViewModelStudent")
              .Columns(columns =>
                {
                columns.Bound(p => p.StudentName).Title("Studnet Name")Width(100);
                columns.Bound(p => p.Sex).Title("Studnet Sex")Width(100);
                columns.Bound(p => p.BirthDate).Title("Student BirthDate").Format("{0:yyyy-MM-dd}").Visible(false);
                 })
                 .Navigatable()
                 .Scrollable()
                 .Sortable()
                 .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
                  .Ajax()
                  .Read(read => read.Action("GetStudentInfo", "Home"))
                            .Group(i => i.Add(a => a.BirthDate))
                    ).AutoBind(true))
```

The group result title is:

**BirthDate: Thu Aug 07 2014 00:00:00 GMT+0800**

How to show the group title like "Student BirthDate:2014-08-07"?

Comment: Have you tried using groupHeaderTemplate ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment you can achieve what you request via GroupHeaderTemplate. I have created an sample for the same.

The only thing you need to add is below code:

```
.GroupHeaderTemplate("Student BirthDate: #=  kendo.toString(value, 'yyyy-MM-dd') #")
```

([Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/D_Learning/2yjsq193/))

Answer (score 1):

This will help you:

```
console.log(kendo.toString(new Date("Wed Apr 08 2015 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)"), "yyyy/MMM/d"));
```